# CSS prefix vs. non-prefix, used twice?

Tags: css

If you have a CSS property with a prefix:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
transform: rotate(10deg);
```

and reach a browser that uses the prefixed version, will it ignore the un-prefixed property or apply the property twice by also processing the prefixed version as well?

Comment: It will not be the case. prefixed versions of properties generally belong to earlier versions. No browser will parse both of them at the same time

Comment: Hey @daremkd you didn't comment or accept the answer. Is you problem solved?

Answer (score 7):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
transform: rotate(10deg);
```

A Browser will parse the attributes in order. If for example webkit reads the `-webkit-transform` but then reads `transform` wich it also knows, it will overwrite the rule of `-webkit-transform`. This technique is called CSS-Fallbacks and is a effect of cascading stylesheets. It will only apply it once, after reading the entire rules.

So in your case it will rotate `10deg` once, and not `10deg` and again `10deg`

Another Example would be:

```css
.test {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

It wont ever apply the color "red", as it is overwritten by "blue" in the same stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing in css as a property applied twice on the same element. Never.

The browser will read them in order and only apply the last one it understands.